# Haskell's polymorphic functions in different GHC version

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am developping vulkan app in haskell in MacOS (M2 gpu).

Code `width    = realToFrac (width (swapchainExtent :: Extent2D))` in following project (`vulkan`)
https://github.com/expipiplus1/vulkan/blob/2007a6ebca9a585028163a850bcedef856fc1e94/examples/sdl-triangle/Main.hs#L283C66-L283C74

Compiled success in `ghc 8.10.7`.
But error in `ghc 9.6.3`.
The error message is

```
/Users/liuzichao/Hulkan/test/Main.hs:283:40: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘width’
    It could refer to
       either the field ‘width’ of record ‘Viewport’,
              imported from ‘Vulkan.Core10’ at test/Main.hs:36:1-30
              (and originally defined in ‘Vulkan.Core10.Pipeline’)
           or the field ‘width’ of record ‘FramebufferCreateInfo’,
              imported from ‘Vulkan.Core10’ at test/Main.hs:36:1-30
              (and originally defined in ‘Vulkan.Core10.Pass’)
           or the field ‘width’ of record ‘Extent3D’,
              imported from ‘Vulkan.Core10’ at test/Main.hs:36:1-30
              (and originally defined in ‘Vulkan.Core10.FundamentalTypes’)
           or the field ‘width’ of record ‘Extent2D’,
              imported from ‘Vulkan.Core10’ at test/Main.hs:36:1-30
              (and originally defined in ‘Vulkan.Core10.FundamentalTypes’)
    |       
283 |               , width    = realToFrac (width (swapchainExtent :: Extent2D))
    |
```

Why this happend? If `ghc 9.6.3` has something different with `ghc 8.10.7`?

Comment: Can you double-check the versions of each library you are using? Especially whatever library or libraries provide the `Vulkan.Core10` family of modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I ran into this same problem trying to follow some Vulkan examples a while back.

A number of changes are being made to record fields based on [this proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0366-no-ambiguous-field-access.rst) which require ambiguous field names to be *much* less ambiguous.  I've found the documentation in the GHC change logs incomplete and confusing as regards *which* parts of this proposal are being rolled out with *which* versions of GHC, though.

However, the following program is accepted by GHC 8.10.7:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

module Field where

data Rect = Rect { width :: Int, height :: Int }
data Circle = Cirlce { width :: Int }

biggerRect :: Rect -> Rect
biggerRect r = r { width = 2 * width (r :: Rect) }
```

compiles but throws some warnings in GHC 9.2.1 (related to the use of the update syntax `width = ...` rather than the `width (r :: Rect)` access), and is rejected outright by 9.4.1:

```
Field.hs:9:32: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘width’
    It could refer to
       either the field ‘width’ of record ‘Circle’,
              defined at Field.hs:6:24
           or the field ‘width’ of record ‘Rect’, defined at Field.hs:5:20
  |
9 | biggerRect r = r { width = 2 * width (r :: Rect) }
  |                                ^^^^^
```

The easiest fix is to use the `OverloadedRecordDot` extension (available since GHC 9.2.0), which lets you write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedRecordDot #-}

biggerRect :: Rect -> Rect
biggerRect r = r { width = 2 * r.width }
```

This still throws a warning on the `width = ...` update part, but it compiles.

For your example above, the following works:

```
, width    = realToFrac swapChainExtent.width
```

and generates no warnings, since this is part of a constructor call, not a record update.

Comment: I handled other ambigous by `OverloadedRecordDot`. How do you handled `size` field ambigous of `MemoryHeap` ?https://github.com/expipiplus1/vulkan/blob/2007a6ebca9a585028163a850bcedef856fc1e94/examples/sdl-triangle/Main.hs#L574C28-L574C32

Comment: `let totalSize = sum $ (\heap -> heap.size) <$> heaps` works. Thanks!